# Почему код не cрабатывает?

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        document.getElementById('operate').onclick = init;
        function init() {
            var firstNumber = parseInt( document.getElementById('fNumber').value );
            var secondNumber = parseInt( document.getElementById('sNumber').value );
            var operator = document.getElementById('operator').value;
            if operator === 'plus' {
                var result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            } else if operator === 'minus' {
                var result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            } else if operator === 'multiply' {
                var result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            } else if operator === 'divide' {
                var result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            } else {
                alert('Ошибка');
            }
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name = 'calculator'>
        <label>Первое число <input type = 'number' id = 'fNumber'></input></label>
        <br>
        <label>Второе число <input type = 'number' id = 'sNumber'></input></label>
        <select id = 'operator'>
            <option value = 'plus'>+</option>
            <option value = 'minus'>-</option>
            <option value = 'multiply'>*</option>
            <option value = 'divide'>/</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button id = 'operate'>Вычислить</button>
        <p>Результат <span id = 'result'></span></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Закрывающего тега `</input>` в природе не существует.  И еще условия `if && else if` должны быть заключены в фигурные скобки  `if(условия)`и еще при присвоении тегам идентификаторов  классов и любого другого элемента не должно быть пробелов, это не правильно -  `id = 'fNumber'`, это правильно `id='fNumber'`... И последнее вроде, зачем делать подобный калькулятор в форме, она тут абсолютно ни к чему...

Comment: Почему не должно быть пробелов?

Comment: Это не такая уж грубая ошибка... Щас не вспомню, но каком-то из браузере не будет работать. Потом будешь искать, что где, да почему... Вроде все правильно, но не работает...  Привыкай сразу верстать грамотно..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в  момент выполнения

```
document.getElementById('operate').onclick = init;
```

на странице еще нет элемента с `id='operate'`.

Перенесите скрипт вниз перед `</body>`, или заверните его в

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  ...
});
```

---

Заодно:

```
<button type='button' id='operate'>Вычислить</button>
```

и

```
if (operator === 'plus') {
```